# Why I can't display remote stream?

Tags: webrtc

I want to make Alice in navig.html able to call Seb in index.html with a live video stream.

But in the index.html file, I am not able to display the remote live stream of Alice in index.html file because the video player displays nothing. Why ?

This is Alice, she has an offer (navig.html)

```
<video id="video1" controls ></video>

<script>

navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:true}, success, error);


function success(stream) {
    var video1 = document.querySelector("#video1");
    video1.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video1.play()
    //rtcpeer
    console.log("1")
    var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection()
    pc1.addStream(stream)
    pc1.createOffer().then(function(desc) {
        pc1.setLocalDescription(desc)
        console.log("" + JSON.stringify(desc))
    })
}
function error(err) {
    console.log(err)
}



</script>
```

This is Seb, he wants to receive live stream from Alice using its offer (index.html)

```
<video id="video1" controls ></video>
<textarea></textarea>
<p onclick="finir()">Fini</p>

<script>

function finir() {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:true}, success, error);
}

function success(stream) {
    var champ = document.querySelector("textarea").value
    var texto = JSON.parse(champ)
    console.log(texto)
    var vid2 = document.querySelector("#video1");
    var pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection()
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(texto)
    pc2.createAnswer()
    pc2.onaddstream = function(e) {
        vid2.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
        vid2.play()
    }
}
function error(err) {
    console.log(err)
}



</script>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Oh, if it would be so simple ;).

With WebRTC you also need some kind of signaling protocol to exchange offer/answer between the parties. Please check one of the many WebRTC samples available.

Comment: How about websockets? Can we use websockets for signalling ?

Comment: Of course you can use websockets for signaling. But the exchange protocol you'll have to define it yourself, there's not something standardized. And you have to take into account the supporting browsers, though the ones supporting WebRTC support websockets too.